Nilpotent Lie algebra with one-dimensional Outer derivations?
It is known that for any nilpotent Lie algebra it is possible to construct an outer derivation. My question is if there is any known nilpotent Lie algebra for which the space of outer derivations has exactly dimension one.

the 1-dimensional one :) (but you want a less silly example)

The outer derivation algebra of a Lie algebra $L$ is given by the first adjoint cohomology
$$
H^1(L,L)\cong Der(L)/Inn(L).
$$
There is a result by Dixmier, that the cohomology groups $H^1(L,M)$ of a nilpotent Lie algebra of characteristic zero are at least $2$-dimensional, for $\dim L\ge 2$.
Reference: Dixmier, J., Cohomologie des algèbres de Lie nilpotentes.
($1955$).
